# AWS SES Nodejs SDK - email with dash bounces

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ses

I'm using the aws nodejs SES sdk and emails with to address with something like 'email@host-name.com' appear to all be bouncing even though they exist. Works for other emails without the dash.

I looked and the emails do look like they end up as query parameters, do I just need to individually url encode them? I dont get an error anymore, but I dont have any email address to test with.

```
    var params = {
        Destination: {
            ToAddresses: [
                'email@host-name.com'
            ]
        },
        Message: {
            Body: {
            Html: {
                Data: body
            }
            },
            Subject: {
            Data: subject
            }
        },
        Source:  fromAddress
    };

    ses.sendEmail(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err){
            console.log(err, err.stack);
        } else {
            //sent
        }
    });
```

Comment: check your reputation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up not having to do with the dash. The emails were bouncing because an AWS email service IP was blacklisted.